# How to perform parallel Insert/Update/Delete operations on same table and context in hosted services?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

So basically I have 4 environments SB, NP, PR and DR and I have a API endpoint for each environment. What I'm trying to do is call each API endpoints and get some data and save it into the database. So for all environments, there is only one table which will store all the `apps` with foundation id 1,2,3 and 4 respectively similarly I have tables for `orgs` and `spaces`.

1) I need to update these tables from data that I get from each API endpoints and I need to call each API `every second`. So there is a good chances that previous data is still not stored before new data arrive this is the issue I'm not sure how to solve.

2) To call these endpoints every second I have created hosted services for each environment which also has a logic to save respective data in its table as I shown below.

The problem with this approach is that I'm using the same DBContext for all four hosted services and getting following error which I understand that EF doesn't support parallel operations on same DBcontext, but I don't know how to solve this issue, from docs it can be solved using  `await` but not really sure how I can use that for all 4 hosted services.

I'm trying to implement fire and forget kinda a thing.

> Ambiguity between 'DBContext.Organizations' and
>   'DBContext.Organizations'

```
public class TokenService : DelegatingHandler, IHostedService
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    protected IMemoryCache _cache;
    private Timer _timer;
    public IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;
    protected HttpClient _client_NP;
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

    public TokenService(IConfiguration configuration, IMemoryCache memoryCache, IHttpClientFactory clientFactory, IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        _cache = memoryCache;
        _clientFactory = clientFactory;
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;

        // NamedClients foreach Env.
        _client_NP = _clientFactory.CreateClient("NonProductionEnv");
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _timer = new Timer(GetAccessToken, null, 0, 3300000);
        _timer = new Timer(Heartbeat, null, 1000, 1000);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //Timer does not have a stop. 
        _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async Task<Token> GetToken(Uri authenticationUrl, Dictionary<string, string> authenticationCredentials)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(authenticationCredentials);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(authenticationUrl, content);

        if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            string message = String.Format("POST failed. Received HTTP {0}", response.StatusCode);
            throw new ApplicationException(message);
        }

        string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Token token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(responseString);

        return token;
    }

    private void GetAccessToken(object state)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> authenticationCredentials_np = Configuration.GetSection("NonProductionEnvironment:Credentials").GetChildren().Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Key, x.Value)).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
        Token token_np = GetToken(new Uri(Configuration["NonProductionEnvironment:URL"]), authenticationCredentials_np).Result;

        _client_NP.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token_np.AccessToken}");
    }

    public void Heartbeat(object state)
    {
        // Discard the result
        _ = GetOrg();
    }

    public async Task GetOrg()
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "organizations");
        var response = await _client_NP.SendAsync(request);
        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        OrganizationsClass.OrgsRootObject model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrganizationsClass.OrgsRootObject>(json);

        using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var _DBcontext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DBContext>();

            foreach (var item in model.resources)
            {
                var g = Guid.Parse(item.guid);
                var x = _DBcontext.Organizations.FirstOrDefault(o => o.OrgGuid == g);
                if (x == null)
                {
                    _DBcontext.Organizations.Add(new Organizations
                    {
                        OrgGuid = g,
                        Name = item.name,
                        CreatedAt = item.created_at,
                        UpdatedAt = item.updated_at,
                        Timestamp = DateTime.Now,
                        Foundation = 2
                    });
                }
                else if (x.UpdatedAt != item.updated_at)
                {
                    x.CreatedAt = item.created_at;
                    x.UpdatedAt = item.updated_at;
                    x.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
                }
            }

            await GetSpace();
            await _DBcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }

    public async Task GetSpace()
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "spaces");
            var response = await _client_NP.SendAsync(request);
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            SpacesClass.SpaceRootObject model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SpacesClass.SpaceRootObject>(json);

            using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                var _DBcontext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DBContext>();

                foreach (var item in model.resources)
                {
                    var g = Guid.Parse(item.guid);
                    var x = _DBcontext.Spaces.FirstOrDefault(o => o.SpaceGuid == g);
                    if (x == null)
                    {
                        _DBcontext.Spaces.Add(new Spaces
                        {
                            SpaceGuid = Guid.Parse(item.guid),
                            Name = item.name,
                            CreatedAt = item.created_at,
                            UpdatedAt = item.updated_at,
                            OrgGuid = Guid.Parse(item.relationships.organization.data.guid),
                            Foundation = 2,
                            Timestamp = DateTime.Now
                        });
                    }

                    else if (x.UpdatedAt != item.updated_at)
                    {
                        x.CreatedAt = item.created_at;
                        x.UpdatedAt = item.updated_at;
                        x.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
                    }
                }

                await GetApps();
            }
        }

        public async Task GetApps()
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "apps?per_page=200");
            var response = await _client_NP.SendAsync(request);
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            AppsClass.AppsRootobject model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppsClass.AppsRootobject>(json);
            using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                var _DBcontext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DBContext>();

                foreach (var item in model.resources)
                {
                    var g = Guid.Parse(item.guid);
                    var x = _DBcontext.Apps.FirstOrDefault(o => o.AppGuid == g);

                    if (x == null)
                    {
                        _DBcontext.Apps.Add(new Apps
                        {
                            AppGuid = Guid.Parse(item.guid),
                            Name = item.name,
                            State = item.state,
                            CreatedAt = item.created_at,
                            UpdatedAt = item.updated_at,
                            SpaceGuid = Guid.Parse(item.relationships.space.data.guid),
                            Foundation = 2,
                            Timestamp = DateTime.Now
                        });
                    }

                    else if (x.UpdatedAt != item.updated_at)
                    {
                        x.State = item.state;
                        x.CreatedAt = item.created_at;
                        x.UpdatedAt = item.updated_at;
                        x.DeletedAt = null;
                        x.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Startup:

```
services.AddDbContext<DBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Basically the code for all services is same except `foundation` and `httpclient`.

Can someone guide in right direction?

Comment: Are you getting build error or runtime error? Which line of code gives the error?

Comment: interestingly I see an error on `_DBcontext.Spaces/Apps/Orgs` but applications build and runs but its not saving the data in the database.

Comment: How is `DBContext` registered in the startup? (e.g. singleton, scoped, transient)

Comment: Just have different DbContext for every service.

Comment: Please clarify what's the actual issue. Currently it's quite unclear and sounds like XY problem. First, every method uses **separate** db context instance, so there is no threading issue. Second, only `GetOrg` saves the changes made, `GetSpace` and `GetApps` lack `SaveChanges[Async]`, hence do nothing. Also which line throws the exception in question, what is the exact exception message and exception stack trace?

Comment: @Fabio if I do that I'm getting the above error

Comment: @IvanStoev I have only one `SaveChanges[Async]` because I don't want to hit the database every second there are 3 functions in each service so for every second if I do `SaveChanges[Async]` database will hit 12 times a second and I dont want that the idea behid having having `SaveChanges[Async]` in `GetOrg` only is that once all 3 function get executed, it will wait to comeplete `GetSpace` and `GetApps` and then only  it will do `SaveChanges[Async]`

Comment: @IvanStoev, the exception appears only when I use 2 DBContext on line `_DBContext.Spaces/Orgs/Apps`

Comment: All I can say is that each scope creates different context instance, i.e. separate change tracker, db connection, transaction etc. Or in other words, all 3 `_DbContext` variables hold separate operations to one and the same database. And in order to be applied (`Add` / `Modify` happens only in memory), they need to call `SaveChanges`. If you want single `SaveChanges` for 3 methods, you have to refactor the code in a way so a single place creates/disposes a scope (hence db context), passes the db context instance to the 3 processes and calls `SaveChangesAsync` and the end.

Comment: @IvanStoev can you please help me with refactoring the code? I'm really stuck on this part.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think that your requirement to not hit the database every second is a bit strange. If you want to save data for every second of every day then you will have 86400 records created for each environment every day whatever the case is. This data will need to go in, if it's not every second then every x seconds you will be doing the same amount of work. Also 4 hits per second on any database is not that much, or even 12 per second as looking at your code, thats what it is doing. There is a good change that the data will be saved in under a second. On the project I'm working on our limit for API calls is a second before we look at other ways of storing/processing data and most of our calls go through webapi, store / mutate data in a SQL DB and also update an Elasticsearch index all in under a second, every at peak times during the day with 1,000s of users.
2. Rather than splitting these methods the way you are why don't you do three calls to the APIs (GetOrg, GetSpace, GetApps) and return to one place, then create one DBContext to save all three results. Save and dispose of the DBContext and do it all over again a second later! One DB call in one transaction every second.

So in sudo code:

```
Heartbeat()
{
    var orgResult = GetOrgs()
    var spaceResult = GetSpace()
    var appResult = GetApps()

    var dbContext = blah()

    dbContext.Add(orgResult)
    dbContext.Add(spaceResult)
    dbContext.Add(appResult)

    dbContext.SaveAllThatStuff()
}
```

and for example

```
GetOrgs()
{
    var response = httpClient.Send(orgRequest)
    var orgResult = jsondeserialize(response.Content)

    return orgResult
}
```

Comment: it makes sense but your pseudo code is not helping, I need iterate through each item as I showed in my code.